# Implementing IhttpHandler and IConnectionIdFactory(SignalR) in a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, signalr, ihttphandler

I have a class `SignalRConnection`. Here I want to generate a connectionId for signalR .
I want a new connection Id if the session is null else return the same connection.I tried to implement IhttpHandler for getting the context in the class and `IConnectionIdFactory` for the connectioId.
My Code is Like this:

```
>  public class SignalRConnection :  
    IHttpHandler,IConnectionIdFactory,IRequireSessionState                                
    {
        string conId;
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Session["activeuser_id"] != null)
            {
                conId = context.Session["activeuser_id"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                conId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            }
        }
        public string CreateConnectionId(SignalR.Hosting.IRequest request)
        {
            return conId;
        }
        public string CreateConnectionId(SignalR.Hosting.IRequest request ,string test)
        {
            return conId;
        }
    }
```

the problem here is the `CreateConnectionId` is only executed.I have the config file configured for the httphandler.I want the the conId to be generated from ProcessRequest and the the `CreateConnectionId` serve the `ConnectionId` to the SignalR Connection.Can It be obtained or am i heading the wrong direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IConnectionFactory is no longer supported in the latest version of SignalR.  See [SignalR 1.0 beta connection factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350158/signalr-1-0-beta-connection-factory/14350859#14350859) for recommendations on better ways to get the same behavior.