# SignalR chat across multiple pages

Tags: .net, chat, signalr

I am working on a learning management system and I have a requirement with the Exam module for students to be able to ask questions during the exam via 1 to 1 chat with a professor. Basically student would ask a question related to an exam question and then professor would respond to that specific student. I thought this would be an ideal use case to try out SignalR.

So I setup the basic example following this link (http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) but I'm confused as to hot to proceed considering my requirements which are:

1. Conversation is always between professor and a single student that asked the original question.
2. The page where professor views/receives the questions and the page were student asks questions are two different pages.

So my questions are:

1. Can SignalR be used to where messages posted by client on one page are delivered to the client on another?
2. How would I target a specific client preferably via User ID from my app and not connection ID of the SignalR's client? Is there a way to set the connectionID and how? What is the correct approach here? Obviously I can pass my user ID to client and have some sort of JavaScript to validate that returned user id is the same as the client's user ID. But is this the proper way to do this?

I appologize for the lengthy wall of text and any advise would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, you can even use SignalR to deliver messages to clients on a completely seperate domain.
2. Clients.Client("The Connection ID you want to send to").
   No, you can access it via Context.ConnectionId.
   Best practices for managing Connection Ids [SignalR 1.0 beta connection factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350158/signalr-1-0-beta-connection-factory/14350859#14350859).
   You never want to have validation client side because it can easily be altered, do authentication server side.

Lastly if you're looking for a sample that is all about Chat checkout [JabbR](http://jabbr.net), it's open source! https://github.com/davidfowl/JabbR.

Hope this helps!