# How to set SignalR custom ClientIds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I want to set SignalR ClientIds to their user's identifiers, stored in the cookies, to easely get them from hubs. How can I do it in SignalR version 0.5 and higher? There's solution on [this page](http://www.kevgriffin.com/maintaining-signalr-connectionids-across-page-instances/), but IConnectionIdFactory is deprecated in new versions of SignalR, so it doesn't work. Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the IConnectionIdFactory is now deprecated you need to maintain your own mappings of users to connection id's.

See '[SignalR 1.0 beta connection factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350158/signalr-1-0-beta-connection-factory/14350859#14350859)' for recommend practices on doing this.