# Reusing same connection in signalR while navigating through different pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, websocket, signalr

I have an MVC project, with multiple pages.

I have a long running process, which updates the client on its progress. However, this update is sent only to a single client, instead of broadcasting to all.

```
Clients.Client(ConnectionId).sendMessage(msg);
```

In my layout.cshtml, this is how I connect to the hub

```
    var serverHub = $.connection.notifier;
    window.hubReady = $.connection.hub.start(function () { });
```

The problem is, when I navigate to another page, I no longer receive the messages from signalr, because the connection id has changed.

How should I workaround this issue, such that my signalr hub can still send messages to a single client, while the client navigates from page to page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will want to create a server mapping of users to connection id's.  See: [SignalR 1.0 beta connection factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350158/signalr-1-0-beta-connection-factory/14350859#14350859).

You will want to let your users persist past an OnDisconnected event and when they connect with a different connection Id you can continue pumping data down to them.

So the thought process could be as follows:

1. Page loads, SignalR connection is instantiated
2. Once connection is fully started call => TryCreateUser (returns a user, whether it existed or it was created).
3. Long Running process Starts
4. Client changes pages -> SignalR connection stops
5. New Page loads, new SignalR connection is instantiated
6. Once connection is fully started see if you have a cookie, session, or some type of data representing who you are => TryCreateUser(userData) (returns the user you created on the last page).
7. Data continues pumping down to user.

**Note:** if you take an authentication approach you will have to be authenticated prior to starting a connection and that data cannot change during the lifetime of a SignalR connection, it can only be created/modified while the connection is in the disconnected state.

Comment: AM facing the same issue, on page navigation. What if a tab remain same and only view get change?? When redirection occurs new I'd generated.