# SignalR winform client with two FORMs

Tags: c#, winforms, signalr

my question may seems very stupid

i am working on SIGNALR and now for practice im writing a chat app with one server( ASP.net only for pushing data ) and clients( winForm something like yahoo)...

**Problem** is that on my client(desktopApp winform ) i have two Forms.
Form 1 is for **LOGIN** and after successfull login the form 2 will be open but in form 2 also i need to connect to the **HUB** and this means another **connectionID** and freak me out ......i can handle it by again updating the connectioId to the user but i wondering to kow if there is any  *clean shot*

Comment: Create a "ChatClient" class which handles all the comms and put it somewhere where both forms have access to it.

Comment: Have a look at this: [Reusing same connection in signalR while navigating through different pages][1]
[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16077519/reusing-same-connection-in-signalr-while-navigating-through-different-pages